# A problem about the field of rational functions over finite field

Tags: contest-math, finite-fields, rational-functions, galois-extensions

Let $p$ be a prime number, and let $F_{p}$ be the finite field with $p$ elements. Let $F=F_{p}(t)$ be the field of rational functions over $F_{p}$ . Consider all subfields of $F$ such that $F/C$ is a finite Galois extension.

1. Show that among such subfields, there is a smallest one $C_{0}$ , i.e. $C_{0}$ is contained in any other $C$.
2. What is the degree of $F/C_{0}$?

Comment: This is a problem from S.-T. Yau college student mathematics contest 2019.

Comment: And what have You tried?

Comment: Do you know what the automorphisms of $F$ look like?

Comment: Because this is from a contest on this year, we need to, by the site rules, make sure that the contest is over. Can you give a link to the contest web page, please? I am not suspecting anything, but otherwise I'm not gonna answer.

Comment: During the contest, I forgot to consider the automorphisms of $F$, and I thought it’s wrong because of a stupid mistake. I’ve solved the problem now. Thank you for your anwser!

Comment: http://www.cms.zju.edu.cn/conference/ycmc/rules.html     This is the link to the contest web page.

Answer (score 1):

$$Aut(k(t)/k) = PGL_2(k)$$ For $k=\Bbb{F}_p$ this is a finite group and $Aut(k(t)/k)=Aut(k(t))$, so $C_0$ is the subfield fixed by $PGL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)$ and $$[\Bbb{F}_p(t):C_0]= |PGL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)| =\frac{|GL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)|}{|\Bbb{F}_p^{\times }|}= \frac{(p^2-1)(p^2-p)}{p-1}=N_p$$

Write $$\prod_{g\in PGL_2(\Bbb{F}_p)} (X-g(t)) = \sum_{n=0}^{N_p} a_n X^n$$
then $C_0=\Bbb{F}_p(a_n)$ for any non-constant coefficient $a_n$
(this is because $a_n$ has at most $N_p$ poles so $[\Bbb{F}_p(t):\Bbb{F}_p(a_n)]\le N_p$)

$n=0$ never works and $n=N_p-1$ won't work for $p$ odd, it doesn't have to be obvious which $n=n(p)$ works.

Comment: Good stuff! I'm very curious about the possibility of a simpler description of the subfield of invariants. In the case $p=2$ the Galois group is the well known group of six linear fractional transformations, and that has been worked out on the site already (IIRC I once did the exercise myself). Of course, by Lüroth's theorem we knew in advance that the field of invariants is a simple purely transcendental extension of $\Bbb{F}_p$.

Comment: There are only $2p(p^2-1)$ choices for $s$ such that $C_0=\Bbb{F}_p(s)$ so it is worth trying a few $p,a_n$ to check if there is a pattern. @JyrkiLahtonen